# Drawing Boy surface by Asymptote, pgfplots

Tags: 3d

This link point to a discussion about Boy surface [3D representation of a Boy surface using a mesh of tubes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291220/3d-representation-of-a-boy-surface-using-a-mesh-of-tubes), Drawing by Mathematica.

Is it possible to draw Boy surface with Pgfplots,Pstricks, Asymptote or Metapost. Boy's surface can be parametrized in several ways :See  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy%27s_surface) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoySurface.html).

I didn't find any questions asked before. I don't know how to start.

Comment: It's possibile but not easy, see here for a starting point https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347716/how-to-color-a-girls-skin

Comment: you knew the parameterization equations, then you can draw it https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661992/140722